# Firebase functions insert for a pre-defined key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an iOS project that has firebase integrated in it. The app has 2 parts: an iPhone and an iPad counterpart and is a food delivery app.
When the iPhone client app adds an order, the vendor sets a listener on `.value` for orders and displays accordingly.
For my specific issue, I have payments enabled as well and I have a thing called `pending` orders (just until the payment is accepted. Once that happens, the pending orders are being deleted and transitioned to open ones. This is the major issue, because the updated open order object still has a reference to the old pending and deleted order and when I try to accept the order on the vendor side, I am still holding the reference to the pending order's id)

```js
const updatePendingOrderToOpenOrderHandler = async (data, context) => {
    try {
        if (!context.auth) {
            // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
        }

        const orderId = data.orderId;
        if (!orderId) {
            throw new Error('There\'s no order id!');
        }
        const ids = orderId.split('/');
        if (ids.length !== 2) {
            throw new Error('The order id is invalid!');
        }
        const vendorID = ids[0];
        const vendorOrderID = ids[1];

        const orderSnapshot = await db.ref(`/orders/vendor/pending/${vendorID}/${vendorOrderID}`).once('value');
        const order = orderSnapshot.val();

        const vendorOpenOrder = await db.ref(`/orders/vendor/open/${vendorID}`).push(order);

        const newOpenOrderId = vendorOpenOrder.key;
        const userId = context.auth.uid;
        if (!userId) {
            throw new Error('There\'s no user id!');
        }

        // delete the pending orders
        await db.ref(`/orders/vendor/pending/${vendorID}/${vendorOrderID}`).remove();
        await db.ref(`/orders/user/${userId}/pending`).remove();

        const newOpenUserOrderId = vendorOrderString(vendorID, newOpenOrderId);

        await db.ref(`/orders/user/${userId}`).update({ 'open' : newOpenUserOrderId});

        // We update the newly created open order with its actual id, because the old id (of the former pending order) is irrelevant now
        // the order status is no longer 'pending', since the payment was approved. so update it to 'submitted' as well
        await db.ref(`/orders/vendor/open/${vendorID}/${newOpenOrderId}`).update({ 
                'id' : newOpenOrderId, 
                'orderStatus': 'submitted'
        });

        return { openUserOrderId: newOpenUserOrderId };
    } catch (error) {
        const { message } = error;
        console.error(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('aborted', message);
    }
};
```

This is the culprit :

```
> const vendorOpenOrder = await db.ref(`/orders/vendor/open/${vendorID}`).push(order);
```

This is when the vendor notifies itself and shows an alert for accepting the order, but it has the id from the above deleted open one.

I only update its id later with (cause I can only get the id of the newly entered value after the `push` call)

```
await db.ref(`/orders/vendor/open/${vendorID}/${newOpenOrderId}`).update({ 
                'id' : newOpenOrderId, 
                'orderStatus': 'submitted'
        });
```

Is there any way I can push with a key of my own or something similar?
I'm struggling for a few days and still haven't come up with a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Danut. Would it be possible to add to your question a diagram that illustrates your workflow? I've tried to dive into your code but, IMHO, it is quite difficult to understand how things work and what is your exact problem. If you could put more context or a create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would help us helping you!

Comment: Thank you Renaud. I just want to push a dictionary/object via javascript in Firebase Realtime Database for a key that I already have
I ended up doing a workaround and just filtering my data when it gets in via the observers

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the Firebase push key ahead of time (it is generated by the client, not the server) and then read it into a variable. You can then post data to the db using the saved key.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

```
// Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
var newPostRef = postsRef.push();

// Get the unique key generated by push()
var postId = newPostRef.key;
```

**Update:**
Here's an example in Unity code from the Firebase docs that shows using .push().key together to retrieve a key that is then used later.

"
To create a LeaderboardEntry and simultaneously update it to the recent score feed and the user's own score list, the game uses code like this:

```
private void WriteNewScore(string userId, int score) {
    // Create new entry at /user-scores/$userid/$scoreid and at
    // /leaderboard/$scoreid simultaneously
    string key = mDatabase.Child("scores").Push().Key;
    LeaderBoardEntry entry = new LeaderBoardEntry(userId, score);
    Dictionary<string, Object> entryValues = entry.ToDictionary();

    Dictionary<string, Object> childUpdates = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    childUpdates["/scores/" + key] = entryValues;
    childUpdates["/user-scores/" + userId + "/" + key] = entryValues;

    mDatabase.UpdateChildrenAsync(childUpdates);
}
```

This example uses Push() to create an entry in the node containing entries for all users at /scores/$key and simultaneously retrieve the key with Key. The key can then be used to create a second entry in the user's scores at /user-scores/$userid/$key.

Using these paths, you can perform simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree with a single call to UpdateChildrenAsync(), such as how this example creates the new entry in both locations. Simultaneous updates made this way are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.
"

Comment: That's what I already have, Graham const vendorOpenOrder = await db.ref(`/orders/vendor/open/${vendorID}`).push(order);

        const newOpenOrderId = vendorOpenOrder.key;